# If two black holes about to collide head on, will there be interference pattern in the space in between?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, interference, gravitational-waves

Imagine massive object such as 2 non spinning blackholes accelerate towards each other, just before they collides I wonder what would the region of space in between them would look like? Will it be interference pattern of gravitational wave or a smooth gradient of spacetime curvature?

Comment: have you seen the LIGO data ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrqbfT8qcBc

Comment: @annav: I just watched however they are both spiralling around each other, I am wondering how about head on collision no inspiral ;)

Comment: there is this duplicate https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26465/would-ligo-detect-head-on-collision